# Flutter - save file to download folder - downloads_path_provider

Tags: android, flutter

I'm developing a mobile app using flutter. For that I used [downloads-path-provider](https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider) to get the download directory of the mobile phone. The emulator returns `/storage/emulated/0/Download`. Also when I save a file in this directory the file can be visible in the Download folder.

But on a real devices it also returns the same directory path. `/storage/emulated/0/Download` Is this correct for the actual devices? Because on actual devices I cannot see the saved file in the Download folder.

Is there any solution to find the downloads directory on a real device?

Comment: Did you add permission on the android manifest file?

Comment: yes @Jotcode. I added both WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: The Download path is correct. How do you try to see it? Which Android version?

Comment: I tried it by printing path. DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory

Comment: android version is 9 and 10

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'm facing the same, can't see files/folders I create on through the app.

Comment: @ErickLangfordXenes after added permission_handler and request permissions it works.

Comment: I'm able to see files on the device but not through a PC connection, was the same problem you face?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

path_provider will probably undergo some changes soon, there are some open issues:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35783

As of right now, the best way to get the download path on an Android device is to use:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/
```

No (s) needed.

And to get the external dir path in Android:

```
/storage/emulated/0/
```

The "emulated" word does not mean it's the emulator path, it's just a naming convention.

Make sure you have permission to write to the file, add this to manifest.xml file, right under <manifest tag:

```
<manifest package="..." ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and also request permission at run time.

See https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Download/` is not the system download folder. It should be `Downloads` with an `s`. However on my OnePlus6, even with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission I still cannot save files directly under there.

Comment: The folder name is correct. You also might need to request permission at run time if you don't have permission.

Comment: Doesnt work for me with "Download" (folder exists, but image wont be saved there) nor "Downloads" (folder does not exist) on Android 11

Comment: for iPhone, what is the path variable for common downloads folder?

Comment: I get a permission error despite setting the manifest permission as above and `Permission.storage.request()` at runtime.

Comment: if `compileSDK` > 32 then see https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/pull/870

Answer (score 9):

add this to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then use these 2 packages:

1. permission_handler to request storage permission
2. downloads_path_provider to save the file in downloads directory

in pubspec add:

```
permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
downloads_path_provider: ^0.1.0
```

then

```
 Future<File> writeFile(Uint8List data, String name) async {
    // storage permission ask
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
    // the downloads folder path
    Directory tempDir = await DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory;
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    var filePath = tempPath + '/$name';
    // 

    // the data
    var bytes = ByteData.view(data.buffer);
    final buffer = bytes.buffer;
    // save the data in the path
    return File(filePath).writeAsBytes(buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
  }
```

then use the method:

```
var file = await writeFile(uint8List, 'name');
```

Comment: Note that 'downloads_path_provider' library is discontinued and should not be used

Comment: @LeonardoRignanese do you have any recommendations on what to use instead?

Comment: @Myzel394 currently using https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider support all os.

Answer (score 4):

just adding to @live-love answer

This code handles iOS normal way using `path_provider` package but for android it uses direct Downloads path, also taking the precaution that on some devices it may be `Downloads` with an `s`

```
bool dirDownloadExists = true;
var directory;
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  directory = await getDownloadsDirectory();
} else {

  directory = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/";

   dirDownloadExists = await Directory(directory).exists();
  if(dirDownloadExists){
    directory = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/";
  }else{
    directory = "/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This question and answer is deprecated with flutter 3.0+ :  [try this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72530115/flutter-download-a-file-from-url-automatically-to-downloads-directory)

```
Future<void> _prepareSaveDir() async {
    _localPath = (await _findLocalPath())!;

    print(_localPath);
    final savedDir = Directory(_localPath);
    bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
    if (!hasExisted) {
      savedDir.create();
    }
  }

  Future<String?> _findLocalPath() async {
    if (platform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      return "/sdcard/download/";
    } else {
      var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      return directory.path + Platform.pathSeparator + 'Download';
    }
  }
```

one method for create or find directory and other one will find path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "flutter_file_dialog" to handle the issue. After succesfully saving file into app you can provide the path of file to this package and save it in another folder of phone. You can use the function below; ** fromDest ** is the path of the saved file.

```
_saveFileToDest(String fromDest) async {
   final params =
            SaveFileDialogParams(sourceFilePath: fromDest);
        final filePath = await FlutterFileDialog.saveFile(params: params);
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print(filePath);
        }
  }
```