# path directory in flutter using path_provider

Tags: flutter, dart, download, storage

In my app I am downloading a files from server. I need to save this files to downloads folder in mobile phone storage. Can this was possible using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package in android ?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61966810/15117201).

Checkout this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62087942/15117201)

You might want to consider saving the files in your app directory of your app, as described in the official pub.dev docs of [path_provider.](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) for downloading and [downloads_path_provider_28](https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider_28) for getting download folder path collectively for this:

```
Future download(String url) async {
  final Dio dio = Dio();
  Directory? downloadsDirectory = await DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory; // "/storage/emulated/0/Download"
  final savePath = downloadsDirectory?.path;
  try {
    Response response = await dio.get(
      url,
      onReceiveProgress: (received, total) {
        if (total != -1) {
          print((received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%");
        }
      },
      options: Options(
        responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
        followRedirects: false,
        validateStatus: (status) {
          return status < 500;
        }
      ),
    );
    print(response.headers);
    File file = File(savePath);
    var raf = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
    // response.data is List<int> type
    raf.writeFromSync(response.data);
    await raf.close();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: ext_storage is not a null safe package. How can we make it in path_provider package ?

Comment: it is not possible to get this download directory from path_provider. And I have updated the library used to the null safe one.