# Downlad file to Downloads directory in android flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter for Android/iOS application. The problem is I have a downloadable link but I cannot download it to downloads directory. How can I do this in flutter. I searched some plugins but they are old and not much usable. Do you know any idea/library on how to do it?

Comment: i think this can help you:https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/download/q/platform/flutter/

Comment: this is also saving to internal storage. I need to save to downloads directory

Comment: then here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966810/flutter-save-file-to-download-folder-downloads-path-provider

Comment: This also didn't help me. These are old answers and android sdk 30 doesn't suppor these

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) plugin. It has a builtin `getDownloadsDirectory()` method that gets you the path you want.

Comment: This doesn't work. It work only on desktop operating systems. It throws exception on Android/iOS

Comment: Well you can just open divert the user to a web-view/browser via `url_launcher`: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

The user can just download it by themselves. Or do you want to use the file within the app?

Comment: That's also good idea! I actually downloaded it into temporary directory and used share file functionality to share it to anywhere the user wants.