# Edit and save document into a preferred directory in iPhone

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using WPS office to edit document into my Flutter app. But, WPS office allows only to **save** into `Document/Local` directory. I can't access any other directory even while I'm opening a document with WPS office manually. How can I save or save as(replace the document with previous one) the edited document into Download/some other directory. I need to save and replace the document into `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you cannot access the directory of other apps on your phone, this is why some users resort to "rooting" or "jailbreaking" their phone, depending on the platform.

If I understand your question, this is what you need. (at your own risk, maybe evaluate if there is any other way of solving your issue before choosing this route.)

Comment: If I want to save the edited file into Download directory I can't store the file in that directory? Like in Android phone we can choose the directory(download/document/etc) where we want to save the file or save and replace the file. I need this things to do in iPhone.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966810/flutter-save-file-to-download-folder-downloads-path-provider

Comment: I can download the file into a directory but can't save and replace that file into same directory. I want to edit the file with MS word/WPS office and replace the edited file with previous one and lastly I've uploaded the edited file from that directory.

Comment: What my concern is how can I edit and save the file into the downloaded location. Cause WPS office allows only to save into Document/Local directory.