# Flutter download a file from url automatically to downloads directory

Tags: flutter, https

Is there a way or a package in Flutter that downloads a file directly to downloads folder for Android and iOS from a direct URL for example: https://******/image.jpg, without any user overhead just a click and download..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes use following packages to completely achieve it :

```
dio: ^4.0.0
path_provider: ^2.0.2
permission_handler: ^8.0.0+2
```

then use following code :

define variables:

```
late String _localPath;
late bool _permissionReady;
late TargetPlatform? platform;
```

get device platform in `initState()`

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      platform = TargetPlatform.android;
    } else {
      platform = TargetPlatform.iOS;
    }
  }
```

for check and requesting device's permissions :

```
  Future<bool> _checkPermission() async {
    if (platform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      final status = await Permission.storage.status;
      if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        final result = await Permission.storage.request();
        if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

prepare for finding localpath :

```
Future<void> _prepareSaveDir() async {
    _localPath = (await _findLocalPath())!;

    print(_localPath);
    final savedDir = Directory(_localPath);
    bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
    if (!hasExisted) {
      savedDir.create();
    }
  }

  Future<String?> _findLocalPath() async {
    if (platform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      return "/sdcard/download/";
    } else {
      var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      return directory.path + Platform.pathSeparator + 'Download';
    }
  }
```

and at last for downloading file:

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () async {
          _permissionReady = await _checkPermission();
          if (_permissionReady) {
            await _prepareSaveDir();
            print("Downloading");
            try {
              await Dio().download("https://******/image.jpg",
                  _localPath + "/" + "filename.jpg");
              print("Download Completed.");
            } catch (e) {
              print("Download Failed.\n\n" + e.toString());
            }
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Icon(Icons.download, color: Colors.black),
        ));
```

Make sure you have added required permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

**EDIT** :

if your app directory is not shown in iOS files then add the below line in `Info.plist`

```
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: I have a question, is this downloads path for android "/sdcard/download/" always correct? seems to be incosistent, some devices work well, some devices return an error
FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/sdcard/download//******.pdf' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

despite having all the permissions needed

Comment: try with '`/storage/emulated/0/Download'`

Comment: simple and self explanatory !!! works like charm.

Comment: @VishalThakkar How can I add `progress indicator` till file download in above example I have try this its working well I have try to add `progress indicator` as well as `display downloading in notification` bar in that but not found proper solution can you help me in that

Comment: This solution really works. Thanks, I was looking for this for hours. Really apreciate

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package to download any file.

> A powerful Http client for Dart, which supports Interceptors, Global
> configuration, FormData, Request Cancellation, File downloading,
> Timeout etc.

**Example**

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
var dio = Dio();
response = await dio.download('https://******/image.jpg');
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is related to downloading a file into the Downloads directory, and not just downloading a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem OS Error Permission denied errno = 13, then I have solution

If you are using path_provider and dio API then you face this problem

you just have to use flutter_file_downloader: ^1.1.0+1 dependency.. go for pub.dev and read documentation of this dependency and use it.