# Downloading always fails when using flutter downloader

Tags: flutter, download, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to download an image using the `flutter downloader` package but it always fails with the following logs:

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006) at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.createFileInAppSpecificDir(DownloadWorker.kt:503)
```

How can I solve this issue. I have also added the required code in manifest file.i.e.

```
   <provider
android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
android:exported="false"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
```

Comment: try from below answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72530480/6644765