# Flutter: Download and open pdf (or any file)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dio, flutter-downloader

I have been using Flutter, and recently migrated to the latest stable version of 3.13.2.

I have a form screen which takes a certain number of field inputs and prepares a request to the server. The server in turn sends a response with a link to a pdf. I would like to download this file so it is present for user to open at a latter point from her/his "Files" app (I am doing this for Android and iOS).

Previously, we had been using [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) package to get this job done. The latest policy changes by Google Play have announced that they require that [all apps must target a sdk of at least API level 33](https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk). The flutter_downloader package does not support API 33 yet, and fails to download the file in newer Android versions.

Given its state at the moment, and a lot of [discussion within the community](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader/issues/854) in its Issues tab, we are not sure when we can expect a fix for this.

---

An [alternative to the above package](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader/issues/823) was suggested which is [background_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/background_downloader).

I have been trying my hands at this alternative, but I am facing too many complications migrating to it. There's some unstable behavior with this, a major of which is related to how [streams](https://github.com/781flyingdutchman/background_downloader/issues/133) are implemented in the package's example implementations. I get the impression that the creator of this package is too keen on closing off issues in Github, before a proper conclusion has been reached. So we are not sure if this would be a good choice for a long run.

---

Some of my colleagues in other projects make use of the [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package to download files to user devices. We don't use dio in our application for network implementations, and it sounds a bit of an overkill to have this dependency simply for download purposes. If nothing else works out, I'll probably be resorting to this option too, though.

---

How is the rest of the Flutter community dealing with a download and open file problem for Android and iOS?

Comment: try this to download any file : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72530480/6644765

Comment: @VishalThakkar Thanks, but I did it without using any external packages like dio 

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [flutter_file_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_downloader)? Works for me!

Comment: This package only supports Android. I need a solution that works for both Android and iOS