# How to create a Button that allow user to download a specific file Flutter

Tags: flutter

I create a flutter app and I have this one CSV file that used as a template for user. I want to provide a Button that allow user to download this CSV file, so they can use it to have CSV file that already have our template.

The problem is I don't know if the best way is to first store the file online and get the url and use it on the flutter downloader URL or keep it in the local code asset and refer to that file when user tap the download template button. Currently I'm applying the second option and it doesn't work (I don't know if this option is possible or not), the download always fail. I'm using flutter_downloader package.

How to fix this ?

Here's my code, Is something wrong with my code ?

```
/// Check if the file exist or not
if (await File(externalDir!.path + "/" + fileName).exists()) {
  OpenFilex.open(externalDir!.path + "/" + fileName);
} else {
  /// Download the file if it doesn't exist in the user's device
  final String localPath = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  /// Dummy file name I want use (it exist in my asset dir"
  const String fileName = 'add.png';

  final data = await rootBundle.load('assets/logo/add.png');
  final bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();

  final File file = File('$localPath/$fileName');
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

  /// Download the file
  final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
    url: '',
    savedDir: localPath,
    fileName: fileName,
    showNotification: true,
    openFileFromNotification: true,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To load a file from the AppBundle and then save it to the users phone, do the following:

- Put the file in assets/filename.csv and declare it in your pubspec like this:

```
flutter:
  assets:
   - assets/filename.csv
```

- Load the file in your code:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show ByteData, rootBundle;

(...)
var data = (await rootBundle.load('assets/filename.csv)).buffer.asInt8List();
```

- Save the data to a file (you need the path-provider package if you want to copy the exact code):

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as pp;
(...)
var path = (await pp.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
var file = File('$path/filename.csv');
await file.writeAsBytes(data, flush: true);
```

Edit: As Stephan correctly pointed out, if you want to store the file in the downloads folder, you will find additional information about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966810/flutter-save-file-to-download-folder-downloads-path-provider). Thank you Stephan!

Comment: Just in addition to Lassios05 great answer: Kim San might want the file to be stored in a place that can be found easier by the user ("one CSV file that used as a template for user"). Maybe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966810/flutter-save-file-to-download-folder-downloads-path-provider are some additional resources to save the file in the Download folder.